# PIC18F452: pressing button doesn't light up the LED

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, programming

I am trying to program a PIC18F452 microcontroller to light up an LED when I press a button. Here are the connections of the keypad:

[image]

The connections for the LEDs:

[image]

The physical connections of the keypad:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
void main() 
{
  char var;

  TRISB = 0xFF; // Set B input
  TRISD = 0x00; // Set D output
  TRISC = 0x00; // Set C output

  while(1)
  {
    PORTD = 0x0E;
    delay_ms(10);
    var = PORTB;

    if (var == 0x00)
    {
      PORTC = 0x01;
    }

    delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

Yet the LED isn't turning on. What errors do I have?

Comment: There is no condition that sets port C pins 0 to 2 high.

Comment: a microcontroller is a completely stupid device ... it does exactly what you tell it to do ... it does not do anything on its own ... do not assume that an LED will light, unless you tell it to light specifically

Comment: There is no code to scan the matrix for button presses. Please explain why do you think the code does, and why do you expect it to work? We don't even know if your LEDs are active high or low as there is no schematics how they are connected, only where they are connected. They might never light up if they are connected incorrectly.

Comment: @Justme They are active high.

Comment: @Justme what do you mean there is no code to scan the matrix for button presses?Inside the while loop I always return the value of PORTB and compare it 0x00.

Comment: @Justme the keypad is pull up so when a button is pressed it changes to low.

Comment: @Velvel sorry typo.

Comment: Even if PORTB is pull-up, please think for a moment what would need to happen for PORTB to read 0x00.

Comment: @Justme Yes your last commment really helped me!

Comment: Furthermore, this will never work reliably since you don't have any debounching of the switches anywhere. It's embedded programming 101 stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PORTB can never read 0x00 to execute your IF statement.